# How to get tweet IDs (since_id, max_id) in tweepy (python)?

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I want to know a way of getting tweet IDs to keep a check on what tweets have been displayed in the timeline of user in the python app I am making using [tweepy](http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/).

There doesn't seem to be a way I get extract the tweet IDs or keep track of them. The parameter to keep check is `since_id`. Please if anyone could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tweepy` library follows the [`twitter API`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) closely. All attributes returned by that API are available on the result objects; so for status messages you need to look at the [`tweet` object description](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets) to see they have an `id` parameter:

```
for status in api.user_timeline():
    print status.id
```

Store the most recent `id` to poll for updates.

Comment: what is the api.user_timeline?

Comment: @Liam: the [Twitter `statuses/user_timeline` collection](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline). Also see the [Tweepy API documentation](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html#timeline-methods).

Comment: But where do you insert the since_id and max_id in the for loop?

Comment: @KrishanVadher: did you look at the documentation I linked to in my last comment?

Comment: I did. I still can't seem to pull tweets after a certain status ID. This is what I have at the moment. How would I change it: max_id = 724916468975046656 for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,twitter).items(count).items(max_id):

Comment: @KrishanVadher: `.items(num)` limits the number of items retured; it does not let you find items before a given tweet ID. I'm not familiar with the Tweepy Cursor API however; perhaps you want to create a new question for this.

Comment: @KrishanVadher: so this is now worthy of a downvote? Because I couldn't help you in the comments? The answer doesn't use Tweepy Cursors.

Comment: Ohh urr. That wasn't me.

Comment: @KrishanVadher: If that's the case then you have my apologies on that. This is an answer from almost 4 years ago with little activity, a sudden downvote very close to some follow-up comments certainly gives the impression that the two events are related.

Answer (score 2):

The `max_id` and `since_id` are parameters for the `api.user_timeline()` method.

Using the `tweepy.Cursor()` object might look something like this:

```
    tweets = []
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,
                       screen_name=<twitter_handle>,
                       since_id = <since_id>
                       ).items(<count>):
        tweets.append(tweet)
```

Comment: This would look better if you formatted your inline a bit better with the multi-line tweepy.Cursor()

Comment: @Danijel-JamesW feel free to edit! Current formatting is according to my pep8 linter :)

Comment: the `since_id` and `max_id` parameter are not working.
No matter what id you put in there,it always return tweet replies from the latest tweet.